# Would a better heat sink be tall or wide?

Tags: design, heatsink

If we have a heatsink and want to improve it's efficiency would it be better to increase its width or height?

What should be the strategy on installing a fan as well?

If we increase height and install fan at top, distance between device and fan increases. The same happens if we increase width and install fan on side.

Should we increase width if we want to install fan on top, and increase height to install on side? Does it even actually make a difference?

Comment: It would have a bigger surface area.

Comment: What do you mean by *efficiency* ?

Comment: Efficiency at taking away heat from the component (peltier element) I am using.

Comment: If the fin orientation and direction of natural convection are along the height, then a taller sink might be better. Or wider if there is forced cooling and/or transverse fins.

Answer (score 3):

If the airflow is vertical (e.g., convection), you want a *wider* heatsink that can contact a larger volume of air. Increasing the height would simply put more heat into air that you've already heated.

Similarly, if the airflow is horizontal, you want a *taller* heatsink.

In either case, you want to make sure that any fins on the heatsink are oriented parallel to the airflow.

Of course, all of this must take into account the constraints of the physical packaging of the product. In general, as long as you increase the total surface area of the heatsink, you'll come out ahead.

Comment: Would the orientation matter if I install a fan over any one accessible side(leaving the side holding the device) ?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of convection, and not forced cooling (i.e without fan), the orientation of the heat sink plays an important role. Vertical orientation (i.e increase in height) is more efficient to a level of 10%, because of the better air movement (cold to hot due to gravity) in an upwards direction.

Comment: Please provide some source for the 10% figure. Thanks.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Heat Transfer Coefficient Constant Kh for a plain plate heat sink in Vertical orientation is 1.42 and for Horizontal (with upper surface hot) is 1.32.

Comment: While the Kh explanation isn't a source but a statement without a source attribution, even so, 1.42 --> 1.32 isn't 10% I believe. Please allow me to reiterate: Could we see a valid source for that statement, please? Also, not sure I understand the "Downvote without..."

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Heat-Transfer-A-Practical-Approach/dp/0072458933 chapter 15 page 815. All the other parameters remains the same except Heat Transfer Coefficient Kh. And yes 7,5% it is at "the level of 10%". I thought you downvote my answer, sorry.

Comment: This looks to me like a good comment, but fails to answer the question about the size of the heatsink.

Comment: @clabacchio. How you can size a heatsink if the power that you are going to dissipate is unknown..at least?

Comment: You shouldn't search, a downvote is just a downvote. And it's not just one voter, it's the sum of up- and downvotes, try to critically analyze your answer to see if you can improve it. I'm going to delete a few comments.

Comment: still wating for the coward rat